# Meteor Template data not loaded during template.autorun()

Tags: meteor, kendo-ui

I'm trying to reactively populate my kendo datasource in my

```
this.autorun(function(){
    datasource.data(Organizations.findOne(thisOrg.data._id));
});
```

which fires properly each time the view is initially rendered, but upon a subsequent template view (not initial render) I get this error in the console which shows that `template.data` is not loaded for some reason:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
at null.<anonymous> (org.js?0330655fbd63766e034cecb907e93089ccc3ef11:129)
at view.js:191
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:437)
at view.js:190
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:523)
at viewAutorun (view.js:189)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:294)
at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:210)
at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:533)
at Blaze.View.autorun (view.js:201)
```

Any ideas? I'm banging my head here. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you have a race condition where the new data is added **after** the autorun fires. Try to check it has been inserted first:

```
this.autorun(function(){
  if (newDataId === thisOrg.data._id) {
    datasource.data(Organizations.findOne(thisOrg.data._id));
 }
});
```

where `newDataId` is the `id` you are targeting . You then need to have previously stored the `id` in the `newDataId` where you do your insert or method call.

Quick sidenote: I advise to store it in a `pageSession` variable (reactive var or reactive dict) rather than in a `Session` var (in order to avoid overcrowding Session).

Comment: You're right about it being a timing thing... I realized after posting this that there is a `.ready()` option in iron router that should actually take care of my timing issue.

Comment: care about the fact that `.ready()` will execute only on your first page load, afaik. I would advise to use this solution only for the first render (I also do it like that) and handle your template refresh with my method.